# EPPlus двухцветный текст

Tags: c#, openxml, epplus

Возможно ли при помощи `EPPlus` в одной ячейке создать, например, 2 слова разного цвета?

Comment: Вот это посмотрите: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9973240/6766879 там есть ответы с разными цветами

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9973240/6766879